# Why does the limit of this function have such a different result than what I expected?

Tags: calculus, limits

So I found this function$$f(x)=x\sqrt{x^2-1}$$Why does it appear that as $x$ gets greater, the function approaches $x^2-0.5$ $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=x^2-\frac12$$I don't understand where the $(-0.5)$ comes from, the only logical conclusion I could make is that it has to do with the $(-1)$ under the square root but I would've assumed it would become negligible eventually, with the function tending towards $x^2$. Why does the function behave like that?

Comment: What you wrote, i.e. $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=x^2-\frac12$$, is false. The expression $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$$ cannot depend on $x$, and in fact, in your case, $$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \infty$$

Comment: The limit of a function is defined to be  unique. Thus such a limit cannot depend on a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the binomial theorem, for $x>0$
$$\sqrt{x^2-1}=x(1-1/x^2)^{1/2}=x\left(1-\frac{1}{2x^2}+\textrm{higher
terms in $1/x^2$}\right)$$
and so
$$f(x)=x^2-\frac12+\textrm{higher terms in $1/x^2$}$$
and these higher terms approach zero as $x\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=x\sqrt{x^2-1}=x^2\sqrt{1-\frac 1{x^2}}$$ Now for small$\epsilon$, $\sqrt{1-\epsilon}\sim 1-\frac \epsilon 2$. Then
$$f(x)=x\sqrt{x^2-1}\sim x^2\left(1-\frac 1 {2x^2} \right)=x^2-\frac 12$$

Answer (score 1):

It is cleaner to write

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(x\sqrt{x^2-1}-x^2\right)=-\frac12,$$

which is easily established by

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(x\sqrt{x^2-1}-x^2\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(x\sqrt{x^2-1})^2-(x^2)^2}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}+x^2}=-\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac 1{\sqrt{1-\dfrac1{x^2}}+1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

see that $$\sqrt{x^2-1}=x\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}= x\left(1-\frac{1}{2x^2}+\frac{1}{6x^4} \cdots \right)$$